# How to stop dashboard sidebar from overlapping with body when expanding tab?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app with the following sidebar. I have the following issue though:

When opening it the "Kontakte" tab will end up overlapping with the dashboard body- is there any way to have the last tab go all the way down and just stay under the second tab?

Also I'd like the expanded tab to be collapsable again, if possible.

I tried researching both online but didn't find how to do it, so any help with one or both of the issues would be appreciated.

```
#LIBRARIES
library (shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library (shinyjs)
library (fresh)
library (ggplot2)
library (shinyscreenshot)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)
library (rdrop2)


#sidebar vordefinieren
Codepan <-   div( id = 'sidebar_cr',
                  conditionalPanel("input.sidebar === 'Main'",
                                   textInput(inputId = "Code", label= HTML("<b>Willkommen auf unserer Auswertungsseite! Bitte gib hier deinen persÃ¶nlichen Code ein.</b><br><em>(Gross- oder Kleinschreibung ist egal) </em>"), placeholder= "z.B. 01ABAB01"),
                                   actionButton (inputId = "Button", label = "Meine Ergebnisse anzeigen"),
                                   box(width = 12, background= "blue",HTML(
                                     "<br><em>Zur Erinnerung:</em> <br> <b> Dein Code setzt sich folgendermaÃen zusammen:</b> <br> <br> 
                        <p><b>1. Der Tag (ohne den Monat) an dem du Geburtstag<br>  hast. </b>
                        <br>Wenn du zum Beispiel am 01.05.2005 geboren wurdest, <br> schreibst du 01, wenn du zum Beispiel am  26.04.2005 <br>geboren wurdest, schreibst du 26.
                        <br>2.<b> Die letzten zwei Buchstaben des Vornamens deines <br> Vaters. </b> 
                        <br>Wenn dein Vater zum Beispiel Georg heisst, schreibst du <br> RG, wenn dein Vater zum Beispiel Max heisst, schreibst <br> du AX.
                        <br>3.<b> Der zweite und dritte Buchstabe deines eigenen <br> Vornamens. </b>
                        <br>Wenn du zum Beispiel Sina heisst, schreibst du IN, <br> wenn du zum Beispiel Leon heisst, schreibst du EO.<br><b>4. Der Geburtsmonat deiner Mutter (als Zahl). </b> 
                        <br>Wenn deine Mutter zum Beispiel im Januar geboren <br> wurde, schreibst du 01, wenn deine Mutter im Oktober <br> geboren wurde, schreibst du 10.<br></p>"))
                                   
                  ))


sidebar <- 
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 350,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = 'sidebar',
      style = "position: relative; overflow: visible;",
      menuItem( "Willkommen!", tabName = 'intro', icon = icon('dashboard'),
                badgeLabel = "Read Me!", badgeColor = "green" ),

      menuItem( "Deine Auswertung", tabName = "Main", icon = icon('barcode')), Codepan,
      menuItem( "Kontakte", tabName = "Kontakte", icon = icon('barcode'))#,
      

    ))


#Body vordefinieren

body <- dashboardBody(

)



# hier beginnt die eigentliche App:
ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Deine Ergebnisse", disable = FALSE),
    sidebar,
    body
  )



server <- function(input, output) {}
  


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: According to documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinydashboard/versions/0.7.1/topics/box) Boxes can be used to hold content in the main body of a dashboard.  However, you are using it in the sidebar.

Comment: In your "Codepan" line, if you change `box(width = 12` to `box(width = NULL` it might be what you are looking for to solve the width part, not the collapsible part.